# Show that the cone over a space is not first countable

Tags: general-topology

> Let $X = \{(n, 0 ) \mid n \in \Bbb N \} \subset \Bbb R^2$. Show that $CX=X \times I/X \times \{1\}$ is not first countable.

If I assume $CX$ is first countable, then $X \times \{1\} \in CX$ should have a countable neighborhood base $\{U_n \mid n \in \Bbb N\}$. Then for any $n$ is the set $\pi^{-1}(U_n)$ an open set in $X \times I$ that contains $X \times \{1\}$? Can I use this to my advantage here to construct a neighborhood of $X \times \{1\} \in CX$ that does not contain any $U_n$?

Comment: More simply, $X=\mathbb N$ (the $×\{0\}$ uselessly complicates the writing, without changing $X$ nor $CX$ up to homeomorphism). Or even (for further reference to [your previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4548763)) $X=\{1−1/n\mid n=2,3,…\}⊂(0,1)$. The proof is then verbatim that of this previous post.

Comment: Aren't these completely different spaces we're talking about? @AnneBauval

Comment: Not that much: in your previous post, we proved that in $((0,1)\times(0,1])/((0,1)\times \{1\})$ (or, for the same reasons, in $C((0,1))=((0,1)\times I)/((0,1)\times \{1\})$), the point $A=(0,1)\times \{1\}$ has no countable neighborhood basis. The proof is exactly the same when you replace the space $(0,1)$ by the subspace $X=\{1−1/n\mid n=2,3,…\}⊂(0,1)$.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken $\pi^{-1}(U_n)$ is the disjoint union of some half-open intervals $[1, c)$ for every $n$-th vertical line? @freakish

Comment: We don't *know* the *hypothetical* neighborhoods $U_n$ of $X\times\{1\}$, except that they are supposed to form a  neighborhoods basis. But since it is a neighborhood, $\pi^{-1}(U_n)$ contains indeed the disjoint union of some $(c_n,1]$ for every $n$-th vertical.

Comment: But I think we know that the preimages of those neighborhoods should contain $X \times \{1\}$ for all $n$. From this I would like to construct an neighborhood such that when mapped back to $CX$ it would contain $X \times \{1\}$, but not any of the supposed neighborhood basis elements. @AnneBauval

Comment: Well, do exactly as in the previous post.

Comment: In the previous post we had some sequence convering to $(1,1)$, but the point $(1,1)$ is only in the $(1,0) \times \{1\}$ vertical interval? I fail to see how these two problems can be combined. @AnneBauval

Comment: The point $(1,1)$ was (happily) not in the set $(1,0) \times \{1\}$ (remember the end of our chat over there: that is what made things work), and won't be in the subset $X \times \{1\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, first of all I will use $X=\mathbb{N}$, since these are homeomorphic.

How to continue your reasoning? Consider $I_n=\{n\}\times I$, which is a subset of $X\times I$, a vertical line, a "ray". Note that all $\{I_n\}$ partition $X\times I$. Let $V_n=\pi^{-1}(U_n)\cap I_n$. So we are doing a diagonal argument: we are looking at the $n$-th piece of $n$-th set.

Since each $U_n$ is an open neighbourhood of $[X\times\{1\}]$, then each $V_n$ is a nonempty open neighbourhood of $(n,1)$ in $X\times I$. Define $V'_n$ to be any proper open subset of $V_n$ containing $(n,1)$.

Finally let $V=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} V'_n$. By the construction $V=\pi^{-1}(\pi(V))$ and thus $\pi(V)$ is an open neighbourhood of $[X\times\{1\}]$. But it also should be clear that none of $U_n$ is contained in $\pi(V)$, by considering its $n$-th "ray".

Comment: There might be a slight problem here because $V$ is not a saturated set since $V_n'$ is  a subset of $V_n$. So the equality in $V=\pi^{-1}(\pi(V))$ should be $V \subset \pi^{-1}(\pi(V))$ I think. @freakish

Comment: @Ricardo $V\subseteq\pi^{-1}(\pi(V))$ is always true, regardless of what $V$ is. The other inclusion follows from two facts: **(1)** $\pi$ is injective everywhere outside $X\times\{1\}$ and **(2)** $X\times\{1\}\subseteq V$ by construction. Anyway, yes, you need to do some manual verification here.

Comment: @Ricardo also note that in our scenario, given $A\subseteq X\times I$ such that $A\cap(X\times\{1\})\neq\emptyset$ , we have: $\pi^{-1}(\pi(A))=A\cup (X\times\{1\})$, which you can verify manually.